# How to use Gmail XLIST command with Zend Framework IMAP?

Tags: php, zend-framework, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I am using the IMAP-module from Zend Framework to interact with Gmail.

But I need to implement to XLIST command (http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/gmail/imap/#xlist) to get folder names. But I don't have any clue how to do this with Zend...

Is there anybody who can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the requestAndResponse method to send arbitrary IMAP commands (from the Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap class, not from the Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap class).

```
$imap = new Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap('imap.gmail.com', '993', true);
// ... login with OAuth etc.
$response = $imap->requestAndResponse('XLIST', $imap->escapeString('', '*'));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think Zend only supports the "list" command wich provides you with local and global folder names.

I have searched the lib for "xlist" and found nothing.

[Zend Mail (Read mails and folders)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html)

Comment: yes but it is possible to do custom fetch operations with Zend. So I think using Xlist is possible...?